# How to replace lastIndexOf URI change with rdfs:label with Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena

I have a following rdf:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali/4491">
    <geontology:length rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1831.99493639</geontology:length>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Fiume chiese</rdfs:label>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">4491</rdfs:label>
    <geo:geometry rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali_4491"/>
  </rdf:Description>
```

My target is to change lastpart of uri change with rdfs: label and rds:label all times contain string only. In the rdf file you see last part of URI is integer so i want to change integer with rdfs:label. So expected output is following:

```xml
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali/Fiume chiese">
        <geontology:length rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">1831.99493639</geontology:length>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Fiume chiese</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali"/>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">4491</rdfs:label>
        <geo:geometry rdf:resource="http://www.territorio.provincia.tn.it/geodati/resource/corsi_d_acqua_naturali_e_artificiali_4491"/>
      </rdf:Description

>
```

Could anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Use `ResourceUtils.renameResource`.

Note that URIs with spaces in are illegal and will give you problems later on.